# Select the floating-point numbers from a file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I want to select the floating-point numbers from a file. What I thought as a solution was this:

```
while ( (ch= getc(fp)) != EOF )
{
   if( isdigit(ch))
      //do some stuff
}
```

However then I saw, that with this approach I get only the integers (but I want the float). So I looked it and I found this:

```
while( (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &n ) == 1)
   //do some stuff
```

I also looked the definition of the `fscanf()` and among other things it says..

> **Return Value**
>
> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets errno to EILSEQ.

However, I don't understand the `while( (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &n ) == 1)`. If `fscanf()` reads a float number will return 1, otherwise will return something else?

Comment: When you say "select", does that mean there is more non-floating point, data in the file that you want to skip over?

Comment: well when I wrote the question I thought so, but I read again more carefully the exercise I have and then the solution and as it seems the program just selects the numbers and then the result is printed to float type. However I kept the question as it is, because I am curious how can I do that (select only the floating numbers).

Answer (score 2):

The `fscanf` call in your code will return `1` if it reads and converts one floating point value. If you had a format asking for two conversions (like, for example, `"%lf %d"`) it would have returned `2` for success. In short, it will return the number of successfully parsed `%` formats you have in the format string.

If the input is *not* a floating point number, then `fscanf` will return `0` and therefore the loop will end. Or if there is an error or you have reached the end of the file it will return `EOF`, which also will break the loop.

Comment: I printed the result of the fscanf (during the loop, was 1) and in case I put a character it returns 0 and it exits from the loop. I tried this `while( (fscanf(fp, "%lf %d", &n ) == 1` as you said to see if it will return 2,but I got a warning ` warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int *’ argument`

Comment: @Nat95 in `fscanf()` provide some variable to hold the value obtained by `%d`, just like , `%if` is having `&n`

Comment: However this doesn't select the floating numbers but all the numbers and the converts them to float. Can I select only the float numbers?